# Which document model to choose in different situations

Tags: design, xml, document

I needed some custom document format and stumbled on this issue. DocBook does it this way

```
<chapter>
    <title>Chapter 1</title>
    <para>Hello world!</para>
    <para>I hope that your day is proceeding <emphasis>splendidly</emphasis>!</para>
</chapter>
<chapter>
    <title>Chapter 2</title>
    <para>Hello again, world!</para>
</chapter>
```

And LaTeX and HTML like (with the same elements as DocBook):

```
<chapter>Chapter 1</chapter>
<para>Hello world!</para>
...
<chapter>Chapter 2</chapter>
<para>Hello again, world!</para>
```

Yes `\chapter` is not an LaTeX environment but I guess this is the most accurate mapping between LaTeX and XML.

When are these different document models to prefer in different cases? In the DocBook case, I can take one chapter out, and it becomes a well-formed document by itself, but there has to be some reason for LaTeX and HTML to not enclose chapters and sections like DocBook does.

Comment: This depends entirely on the requirements for your individual project - but I can tell you this: try to stick to *one* if possible.

Comment: @Zibboz Yes, stick to one. Give some examples of how requirements maps to different solutions.

Comment: No, I'm telling *you* to stick to one - the fewer document template models you're going to have to work with, the easier it will be to implement in the future.  Which one you use is a matter of your individual project requirements - and telling you which one is 'best' would make this a shopping rec question.

Comment: So where can I find pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this difference is simply an anachronism from the age of HTML and LaTeX.

HTML, having evolved out of [SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) (as did [Docbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook)), actually [got a lot of it's *structural* elements (*i.e.* `<h1>`, etc) from IBM's GML/GMLguide languages](http://infomesh.net/html/history/early/).  In [GML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Generalized_Markup_Language), as with LaTeX, the focus of the language designers was on the **presentation** of content, rather than the *communication* of the **structural** composition of that content.

IBM's GML was designed with requirements such as dox-matrix printers (which only had one dot-size).  Hence, a Heading-1 needed to look different some other way from heading-2, etc.  As such, the *height* of a line of text was dependant upon what *content* role it played (*i.e.* as a heading).  To prevent presentation-corruption, programs printing GML documents to dot-matrix line printers needed to know if there were enough *lines* (of dots) available for a heading, etc.

Since HTML borrowed most of these things from GML, it kept the idea of a fairly **flat**, *presentation-oriented* document structure.  Where the floating paragraph under a (sibling) header was inferred as it's child since it was *presented* later in the (structured) document.

With the advancements on the web and rising ubiquity of the Internet, by the time XML came into the fray (mid-to late 90's, standardised in early 2000's), the *communication* (rather than presentation) of the content was what mattered.  As such, XML document designs are usually **much** deeper than those of SGML/HTML/GML.

---

Now, as for an answer to your (somewhat broad?) question... I would agree with [@Zibbobz](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/123958/zibbobz)'s comment - that it does indeed **depend *entirely* upon the requirements for your individual project**.  As a rough guideline, situations where you are dealing with limited hardware (printers, etc), the shallower a structure the better.  But also, in situations where whatever your *document* is representing is clearly a **composition**, then use the composing nature of XML and make things nested!